# Is it possible to create a Blazor scoped CSS file for multiple components without duplicating it?

Tags: c#, blazor

Is it possible to create some sort of component scoped CSS file for multiple components without duplicating it? Is there any naming convention?

Lets assume there are three components which all use the same tags but a style should only be applied for components of naming scheme `ComponentA` . Other components should not be affected.

```
ComponentA_A.razor
ComponentA_B.razor
ComponentOther.razor
```

having

```
ComponentA.razor.css
```

instead of

```
ComponentA_A.razor.css
ComponentA_B.razor.css
```

If duplication is the only way, is it possible to use some kind of referencing in css file itself or referencing a specific css file in blazor component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this, using [custom scope identifier format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-configuration).
It's not very elegant but you might consider it:

- All `.razor` components need to have their respective `.razor.css` files:

  ```
  ComponentA.razor
    ↳ ComponentA.razor.css

  ComponentB.razor 
    ↳ ComponentB.razor.css
  ```
- **One** of the `.razor.css` files contains the css styles, the others can stay empty.
- In your `.csproj` file add the following item group:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="Components\ComponentA.razor.css" CssScope="my-custom-scope" />
      <None Update="Components\ComponentB.razor.css" CssScope="my-custom-scope" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```

This will create the same custom scope `my-custom-scope` for all components it's applied to, and  thus will apply the same styles to them.

Comment: Is this only valid for files inside the same .csproj, can my-custom-scope be extended to other .csproj? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (might not be applicable to the OP but it's a way) is to use a preprocessor like SASS then you can create `mixin`s and `variable`s that are shared across components **but you can also use pure CSS solution nowadays using custom properties (variables).**

So just to give an example using pure CSS you can do something like the following:

1. In your `_Host.cshtml` file add a `link` to a global CSS file (in our example we gonna call it `site.css`) like so:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorWebApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Note, that we added the link to `site.css` above `BlazorWebApp.styles.css` which is a generated file for the CSS, depends on the setup though.

2. Then you can define a CSS variable preferably in the `:root` but it can be anywhere, you can even create a dummy class called `.variables` and declare it there (cascading rules applies) but for the example we gonna stick with `:root` like so:

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #ff0000
}
```

3. And then we can use `--primary-color` across components and we can declare yet another variable say `--component-a-color` and use that for components related to `ComponentA` like so:

**ComponentA_A.razor.css**

```
div {
    --component-a-color: #00ff00
    color: var(--component-a-color);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

**ComponentA_B.razor.css**

```
div {
    color: var(--component-a-color);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

**ComponentOther.razor.css**

```
div {
    color: #0000ff;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

p.s. I'm using separate files for the CSS here but this shouldn't matter.